Proxifier Alternatives
I'm gonna switch to Kubuntu but the only app I didn't found an alternative for is Proxifier, I'm using it on Windows and tunnel any app.exe or web.site from the desired SOCKS5/HTTP Proxy, I found some alternatives already but none of them support per-app proxy.

What do you use "proxifier" for? At AskUbuntu,  we're unfamiliar with Windows tools. Would "packet routing" do what you need?

This question is similar to: Is there any utility like `Proxifier` for Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@waltinator at the company i work we should use a proxy server to access some applications and websites, it was easy until i switched to linux and now i'm searching for a solution

@muru didn't found anything related to using proxy on apps, i don't know how apps work on linux yet (for example windows has a .exe executable file)

Well, for that matter, that post has two mentions of "Route by application", which is just another way of saying "per-app", so I don't see why the specificity here isn't covered there.

After a day of research, I found the best way to do what I wanted from Proxifier
First you need to edit the <name>.desktop in /usr/share/applications to add your HTTP proxy, this is an example for Discord:
Change the Exec= line from this:
Exec=/usr/share/discord/Discord
To this:
Exec=env http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:2081 https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:2081 /usr/share/discord/Discord --proxy-server="http://127.0.0.1:2081>
Now you can normally launch the application and it uses a Proxy server
Also for websites I use SmartProxy and Proxy SwitchyOmega add-ons (Proxy SwitchyOmega is easier) to route websites through proxy
